# Cannot find module 'typeorm' but installed

Tags: typescript

I'm NEW to TS and I have a problem. When I installed TYPEORM and imported something from it, I got `typeorm not found` returned. It is properly installed and all seems to work except this. Also tried importing it with types but it is not found. Any solution?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Help others reproduce the problem".

Comment: Same problem here. I installed TypeORM: `yarn add typeorm`, then create a script with `import { DataSource } from 'typeorm'`. When I try to run the script, I get *"Cannot find package 'typeorm' imported from ..."*. This happens in TypeScript project *and* JavaScript project.